# Write Insert Query in SQLite3 in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sqlite, insert

Hi need insert data in table if the record is not already exits
Ex: 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT Id FROM table WHERE id=_Id) THEN
 INSERT INTO tbale(.....)

This can be easily done using stored procedure in MySql. But I want to d same thing in SQLite by writing a single query statement.

Pleas help

Comment: I'm happy for you! Tried checking out documentation for sqllite first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

INSERT INTO CategoryMaster (CategoryID, CategoryText) SELECT %d,'%@' WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CategoryMaster WHERE CategoryID= %d)

Its working for me :)

Answer (score 1):

SQlite doesn't have stored procedudes that you need to do logic like this. But you can always extend sqlite with simple C-functions. Or you could simply code this logic in whatever language you are writing your program in. I don't think the performance hit is that great. Did your profiling show that this is a critical path that needs to be optimized?

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique index on the id column (or make it the primary key) then use:

```
REPLACE INTO table(.....)
```

see:
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html or http://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by running a first query to see if the record exists then decide whether to run an insert or update.  I don't think SQLite has a fully featured query language to support the desired shorter approach.